# Whats wrong with this MERGE

Tags: sql, teradata

whats wrong with this merge statement , i have multiple update conditions on matching,
i have provided moore join conditions in 'when matched', but its not working

```
    MERGE INTO DATABASE1.TARGET AS KEY_SBSCR
    USING (
        SELECT
         SOURCE_KEY
        ,DOMAIN_NAME
        ,EDW_KEY
        ,CUSTOMER_ID
        ,START_DATE
        ,END_DATE
        ,PROCESS_ID
        ,UPDATE_PROCESS_ID
        ,NEG_UPD_FLAG
        ,FILEID
        ,CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SOURCE_KEY) +(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(EDW_KEY),'0') FROM DATABASE1.TARGET) AS INTEGER) as NEW_KEY
    FROM TARGET.TEST
    ) AS KEY_TEMP
    ON KEY_SBSCR.EDW_KEY=KEY_TEMP.EDW_KEY
    WHEN MATCHED AND KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE=CAST('99991231' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') 
                THEN
                                    UPDATE SET  KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE=KEY_TEMP.END_DATE
                                                                ,KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID=KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID    
    WHEN MATCHED AND    KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL 
        THEN 
                            UPDATE SET  KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID=KEY_TEMP.CUSTOMER_ID
                                                        ,KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID=KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED  BY KEY_SBSCR THEN
                                    INSERT (SOURCE_KEY,DOMAIN_NAME,EDW_KEY,CUSTOMER_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,PROCESS_ID,UPDATE_PROCESS_ID,NEG_UPD_FLAG,FILEID)
                            VALUES (SOURCE_KEY,DOMAIN_NAME,NEW_KEY,CUSTOMER_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,PROCESS_ID,UPDATE_PROCESS_ID,NEG_UPD_FLAG,FILEID)
```

thanks

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: WHAT'S WITH THE CAPS?

Comment: And what does "its not working" actually mean?

Comment: Sir, your caps lock appears to be stuck.

Comment: sorry guys , was writing query ,, so caps was on

Comment: You still haven't said *how* the code doesn't work.  You know, for example, error messages or something

Comment: It says 'expected something between the word MATCHED and the AND keyword'.

Comment: everyone said caps was on , anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks like SQL Server syntax, but Teradata doesn't support multiple WHEN MATCHED plus ANDed conditions...

I don't know if this workaround actually works, but you might try to combine both conditions into one:

```
MERGE
....
ON KEY_SBSCR.EDW_KEY=KEY_TEMP.EDW_KEY
AND (KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE=CAST('99991231' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')
     OR KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
         KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE=CASE WHEN KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE=CAST('99991231' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'
                                 THEN KEY_TEMP.END_DATE 
                                 ELSE KEY_SBSCR.END_DATE 
                            end
       , KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID=CASE WHEN KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL 
                                    THEN KEY_TEMP.CUSTOMER_ID 
                                    ELSE KEY_SBSCR.CUSTOMER_ID 
                               end
       ,KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID=KEY_SBSCR.UPDATE_PROCESS_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ...
```

Btw, instead of `CAST('99991231' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')` you better use `DATE '9999-12-31'`

Comment: thanks dnoeth, what I can do for this scenario, can I add case in WHEN MATCHED.